# Why can't SynthWave 84 enable Neon Dreams on windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am installing the synthWave 84 theme for VS Code but when I turn on neon it gives an error: You must run VS code with admin privileges in order to enable Neon Dreams.I  tried running VSCode as admin but still not working!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed this on the file extension.js and worked for me:

Path: C:\Users\**"*YourUserName*"**\.vscode\extensions\robbowen.synthwave-vscode-0.1.11\src

```
    const htmlFile =
        base +
        (isWin
            ? "\\electron-sandbox\\workbench\\workbench.html"
            : "/electron-sandbox/workbench/workbench.html");

    const templateFile =
        base +
        (isWin
                ? "\\electron-sandbox\\workbench\\neondreams.js"
                : "/electron-sandbox/workbench/neondreams.js");

    var htmlFile =
        base +
        (isWin
        ? "\\electron-sandbox\\workbench\\workbench.html"
        : "/electron-sandbox/workbench/workbench.html");
```

So, as you can look  where it is written "electron-sandbox", it was "electron-browser" before.

After saving these changes, you run as administrator and try again, then it should work.

Comment: It tells me restart to turn on but when I restart neon still won't turn on... Did I do something wrong?

Comment: It should work with those changes, when I clicked on "Restart editor to complete", it worked for me. Anyway, I updated the changes because it didn't allow me to disable the Neon. I understand that is something with folders because those files should be here "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-sandbox\workbench". It could be your case that those files are located on other folder, if true you should put on those strings the correct path. Something else that could check is if you had installed "System Installer" https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: It seems that other effects such as the hint bulb still work, only the text is not glowing

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and here is what worked for me:

Uninstall the extension.

Delete the folder containing the previous installation; folder is: "robbowen.synthwave".
located at: C:\Users"YourUserName".vscode\extensions

Run VsCode as adm, install the extension, apply neon, it will prompt you to restart vscode, just do it.

It worked for me. If you want to give it a try, it's up to you.

PS: Folder name might be different depending on the extension version.